# Unity Повернуться в направление и повторять рельеф поверхности 2D

Tags: unity3d, rotation, scale

Всех с наступающим! Спасибо этому чудесному сообществу!!!

---

Я не могу решить задачу уровня 7го класса : нужно повернуть **2D** объект в направление пути.

Путь представляет множество **WayPoints**, каждый **WayPoint** знает **нормаль** поверхности.

Я умею вращать объект в зависимости от нормали поверхности, В этом случае мы вращаемся вокруг синей мировой оси - повторяя поверхность.:

```
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, wayPoint.normal);
```

Я могу изменить **Scale**, чтобы повернуться, но изменять размер мне не подходит, я хочу развернуть на 180 градусов. Выше я получил Quaternion но, я не знаю как с ним работать дальше и как его повернуть...

Так же у меня выходило, что я стаю зависим от компонентов X,Y вектора по отдельности и получается, что начинаются скачки туда сюда, мне хотелось бы не зависеть от отдельных компонентов вектора, а зависеть только от направления `(NextWaypoint.Position - WayPoint.Position).normalized`. Но при использовании направления мой объект в обратном направлении переворачивается, что вообще не допустимо..

Я нарисовал примерно то, что я имею ввиду - пути и направления в которых надо меняться и немного описания маркировки:

1. Красные стрелки - направление в сторону куда направляется объект
2. Красная сплошная - путь из **WayPoints**
3. **Y** - ось во круг которой я хочу вращаться и значения вращения.
4. Синие линии - это **Normal** поверхности, где синих линий нет, в этих местах будет игнорироваться повторение поверхности.
5. Зеленые стрелочки - объект для вращения

[image: Вариант первый, кривая]

[image: Вариант второй, линейный путь со сменой направления]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1aBjTa3xQzE в этом видосе и движение по пути и поворачивание капсулы в сторону пути реализовано. Так же есть готовые ассеты которые делают это же в достаточной мере качественно, например PathMagic. На самом деле легче купить PathMagic чем сделать на том же уровне качества.

Comment: @Andrew Спасибо, система поиска и граф путей - это не проблема, я лишь имею небольшую трудность с поворотами в направления пути. Я видео глянул быстро и в целом, я думаю что это полезное видео!

Answer (score 2):

я подумал и решил свою задачу. Выкладываю код, который подходит в рамках моей задачи:

```
// находим направление движения
var dir = nextNode.position - currentNode.position; 
                                                      
// находим угол между направлением пути - dir и взглядом объекта transform.right в 2D
// проверяем если угол больше чем 170 градусов то, вектор направления в другой стороне
// LookLeft булевое публичное свойство, изменяется если направление не правильное
// LookLeft установлено по умолчанию false так как мой объект смотрит изначально вправо.
// LookLeft = !LookLeft применятся пинг-понг, чтобы сменить значение.
if(Vector2.Angle(transform.right, dir) > 170)
{
    LookLeft = !LookLeft;
}

// в моём графе путей, ноды хранят нормаль поверхности всегда статично (это важно)!!!    
// получаем нормаль поверхности если RepeatSurface булевое свойство - разрешено.
var surfaceNormal = RepeatSurface ? nextNode.normal : Vector2.up;

// surfaceRotatation - создаем вращение повторяя поверхность
var surfaceRotatation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector2.up, surfaceNormal);

// pathDirectionRotation - создаем вращение в направление пути с помощью булевой LookLeft
// определяем на сколько повернуть объект то есть 180 - влево или 0 вправо.
var pathDirectionRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, LookLeft ? 180 : 0, 0);

// Умножаем Quaternions чтобы объединить вращение относительно поверхности и
// вращение в сторону пути. Применяем полученное вращение к объекту.
transform.rotation = surfaceRotatation * pathDirectionRotation;
```

Если я не прав или я допустил ошибку, пожалуйста поправьте меня, я решал задачу несколько дней и я допускаю возможность ошибки!!!